# Get the source code from an html file

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting

I am wondering if you could please help with generating .cpp/.h file from the following html file in a programmatic way (using whatever scripting language, or programming language, or even using editors such as vi or emacs):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Class</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body link="blue" vlink="purple" bgcolor="#FFFABB" text="black">

<h2><font face="Helvetica">Code Fragment: Class</font></h2>
</center><br><dl><dd><pre>

  <font color=#A000A0>template</font> &lt;<font color=#A000A0>typename</font> G&gt;
  <font color=#A000A0>class</font> Components : <font color=#A000A0>public</font> DFS&lt;G&gt; {            <font color=#0000FF>// count components</font>
  <font color=#A000A0>private</font>:
    <font color=#A000A0>int</font> nComponents;                 <font color=#0000FF>// num of components</font>
  <font color=#A000A0>public</font>:
    <font color=#000000>Components</font>(<font color=#A000A0>const</font> G& g): DFS&lt;G&gt;(g) {}        <font color=#0000FF>// constructor</font>
    <font color=#A000A0>int</font> <font color=#A000A0>operator</font>()();                 <font color=#0000FF>// count components</font>
  };
</dl>

</body>
</html>
```

If you could please point out how this was done in the other direction too, that would be great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You want a tool to copy the highlighted text in an HTML page?

Comment: What should the generated .cpp and/or .h file *do*?

Comment: @Keith: not sure why you asked that. I just want to be able to switch between this kind of html representation of my c++ code and vice versa. I am asking the programmatic way or any tools that I can use to do that quickly in batch mode.

Comment: @Qiang: Oh, I see what you mean.  I didn't see past the HTML tags to notice that the HTML is a representation of C++ code, so I didn't think the idea of translating HTML to C++ made much sense.  Nevcer mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
[18:56:44 jaidev@~]$ lynx --dump foo.html
Code Fragment: Class


  template <typename G>
  class Components : public DFS<G> {            // count components
  private:
    int nComponents;                 // num of components
  public:
    Components(const G& g): DFS<G>(g) {}        // constructor
    int operator()();                 // count components
  };
[18:56:49 jaidev@~]$
```

**Edit:**

For the reverse direction. If you use vim as your editor, you can enter `:TOhtml` to generate a syntax highlighted HTML version of your code in a new buffer. It generates a html based on your vim colorscheme. To change the colorscheme, use the `:colorscheme <name>` command.

Comment: @Qiang Li: any PHP, Python or JS syntax highlight plugin will do

Comment: Edited answer for the reverse direction.

Comment: @yi_H, can you please be more specific, for example, what is Python's?

Comment: @yi_H: do you mind telling me what formatter did you use to give the nice coloring?

Comment: *sigh* if you can't figure that out you should seek for another job.

Answer (score 2):

PHP script:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("file.html");
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$str = '';
foreach ($xpath->query("//dl//text()") as $node) {
    $str .= $node->nodeValue . ' ';
}

file_put_contents('file.cpp', $str);
```

contents of file.cpp:

```
   template  < typename  G>
   class  Components :  public  DFS<G> {             // count components 
   private :
     int  nComponents;                  // num of components 
   public :
     Components ( const  G& g): DFS<G>(g) {}         // constructor 
     int   operator ()();                  // count components 
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions to...

- ...keep only what's in the `<body>` of the HTML page,
- ...strip all the HTML tags (everything that looks like `<.*>` should be removed from the file).
- ...unescape special characters such as `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;` etc.

What's left should be the code you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for going from HTML to the source code is the [`html2text`](http://www.mbayer.de/html2text/) utility, that is often found installed in many Linux distributions.

```
matteo@teomint:~/Desktop$ html2text out.html 
***** Code Fragment: Class *****


        template <typename G>
        class Components : public DFS<G> {            // count components
        private:
          int nComponents;                 // num of components
        public:
          Components(const G& g): DFS<G>(g) {}        // constructor
          int operator()();                 // count components
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

- Fix the HTML. You're missing some closing tags.
- Get PHP out
- - Obtain the `pre` code block with `DOMDocument`
- - `strip_tags()` from the result
- Profit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to strip all HTML tags to get back the original, non-highlighted source code, then you have a two options that I can think of:

1. Parse the DOM tree and just grab all relevant text.
2. Use some regular expressions to remove the tags themselves. For example, maybe "s///" would be a good start?